# Not rerendering on state change ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

In the arr.js file I have some images. I wrote a function for shuffling the elements in the array. I want react to render the shuffled images when the component is first mounted and also when the images are clicked.

Here is what I tried:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Arr from "../utils/arr";

const MainContainer = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: auto;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
`

const Main = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState(Arr)

    const shuffleArrayOnClick = (Arr) => {
        for (let i = Arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var tmp = Arr[i];
            Arr[i] = Arr[j];
            Arr[j] = tmp;
        }
        return Arr;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const shuffle = shuffleArrayOnClick(Arr);
        setArr(shuffle);
    })

    return (
        <MainContainer onClick={shuffleArrayOnClick}>
            {arr}
        </MainContainer>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

The useEffect runs right after the initial render when no dependency array is set. So I expected the images to be shuffled when the component is first mounted. But the shuffle doesn't work when I reload the page. Instead the images get shuffled and re-rendered when I change my code and save it.
Also how should I set the onclick function on the array elements?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## NEVER MODIFY REACT STATE DIRECLY

```
const shuffleArrayOnClick = (arr) => {
  const Arr = [...arr]
  for (let i = Arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var tmp = Arr[i];
      Arr[i] = Arr[j];
      Arr[j] = tmp;
    }
    return Arr;
}
```

You probably want to run this `useEffect` once, not million times

```
useEffect(() => {
  const shuffle = shuffleArrayOnClick(arr);
  setArr(shuffle);
}, [])
```

Comment: This causes an infinite re-render

Comment: Can you please explain how do I put onclick functions on the array elements?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html